# How do I copy a single element of a list by reference and not by value?

Tags: python, arrays, list

Let's say we have 2D array `foo_arr`:

```
foo_arr = [[None, None, None, None],
           [None, None, None, None],
           [None, None, None, None],
           [None, None, None, None]]
```

Now, I want to be able to access the 2D array from both its rows **and** its columns. For example, I can just do `row_0 = foo_arr[0]`, and any changes to `foo_arr[0]` will be reflected in `row_0`; i.e. if we do this:

```
row_0 = foo_arr[0]
foo_arr[0][0] = (0, 0)
# row_0 == [(0, 0), None, None, None]
```

**I also want to be able to do this with columns.** For example, I want something like `column_0 = [foo_arr[0][0], foo_arr[1][0], foo_arr[2][0], foo_arr[3][0]]`, and when I change `foo_arr` (or `column_0`), they should each be able to see. An illustration of the desired behaviour:

```
column_0 = [foo_arr[i][0] for i in range(4)]
foo_arr[0][0] = (0, 0)
foo_arr[1][0] = (0, 1)
# Desired: column_0 == [(0, 0), (0, 1), None, None]
# Actual: column_0 == [None, None, None, None]
```

---

Essentially, I'd like this, written in C:

```
int** foo_arr = malloc(sizeof(int*)*4);
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    foo_arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
        foo_arr[i][j] = -1; /* Using -1 here to represent None */
    }
}
int* row_0 = foo_arr[0];
int** column_0 = malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    column_0[i] = &foo_arr[i][0]; /* Yes, technically the same as just doing foo_arr[i] for column 0 */
}
/* Changing the 2D array: */
foo_arr[0][0] = 0;
foo_arr[1][0] = 4;
foo_arr[2][0] = 8;
/* We should have:
   *column_0[0] == 0;
   *column_0[1] == 4;
   *column_0[2] == 8; */
```

---

**Is it possible to get this behaviour in Python? Does numpy or other packages have this behaviour?** edit: I'd like to avoid writing a "wrapper" function that just extracts the column. If I'm processing on columns many times, I don't want to generate a new list that represents a column every time I want to operate on columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a straight forward way of doing this with 2D+ lists. But with numpy it's trivial:

```
foo_lst = [[None, None, None, None],
           [None, None, None, None],
           [None, None, None, None],
           [None, None, None, None]]

foo_arr = np.array(foo_lst, dtype=object)
foo_arr[:, 0] = np.arange(4)
```

Result:

```
array([[0, None, None, None],                                                                                         
       [1, None, None, None],                                                                                
       [2, None, None, None],                                                                                
       [3, None, None, None]], dtype=object)
```

If you will *mainly* be dealing with columns of a `list` you can consider taking the transpose:

```
lst2d = [[...], [...], ...]

lst2d_t = [list(col) for col in zip(*lst2d)]
# index the ith "column" like so: lst2d_t[col_no]
```

But numpy is preferable at this point.

Answer (score 0):

so you have some super complicated code, but all you really need is a [`numpy` array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

```
import numpy as np

# foo_arr = np.array(
#     [
#         [None, None, None, None],
#         [None, None, None, None],
#         [None, None, None, None],
#         [None, None, None, None]
#     ]
# )
# or better:
foo_arr = np.empty((4, 4), dtype=object)

row_0 = foo_arr[0, :]
col_0 = foo_arr[:, 0]

foo_arr[1, 0] = (0, 0)
print(row_0, col_0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a type which knows where to look for changes:

```py
class ListRef:
    def __init__(self, collection, index):
        self.collection = collection
        self.index = index
    def get(self):
        return self.collection[self.index]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.get())
    
foo_arr = [[None, None, None, None],
           [None, None, None, None],
           [None, None, None, None],
           [None, None, None, None]]


column_0 = [ListRef(foo_arr[i], 0) for i in range(4)]
print(column_0)

foo_arr[0][0] = (0, 0)
foo_arr[1][0] = (0, 1)
print(column_0)
```

Output:

```py
[None, None, None, None]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), None, None]
```